# display image full screen with opencv

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I'm working with `opencv` for `android` sdk.  I can't display image on full screen.: I'm using:

```
mRgba = Utils.loadResource(MainActivity.this,R.drawable.images,Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRgba.cols(), mRgba.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);        
Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, bmp);
imgView2.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

to display the image.Any idea what I'm doing wrong? The image resolution is 800x480.

Answer (score 0):

You've set the image to an `imageView`. That's not going to make it fullscreen. Instead create another activity with only an `imageView` set it's set style to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`. Now set this `imageView` to your `Bitmap`.

Comment: thank you but I still have the same problem.I added `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` but this doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: i add it in the layout now but the image is not scaled to fit the screen size.It is too big

Comment: Then just scale it to fit the screen size and then set it to the imageView